# Enabling logcat in a ROM that has it disabled

Tags: custom-roms, logging

I'm running [Liquid Smooth 3.2](http://liquidsmoothroms.com/) on my Motorola Droid 1.  This ROM comes with logcat disabled (`/dev/log/main doesn't exist`).  I tried starting the logcat service myself by adding the following to `/etc/init.local.rc`:

```
#start logcat service
service logcat /system/bin/logcat -f /dev/log/main
   oneshot
```

However, this didn't seem to work as `/dev/log/main` still doesn't exist on boot.  I'm getting...

```
$ logcat
logcat
Unable to open log device '/dev/log/main': No such file or directory
```

Does anyone know how to re-enable logcat in a ROM that has it disabled?

Comment: Looks like Franco's Kernel is another that doesn't let you use logcat. Is there any way around it for Franco's? https://www.facebook.com/franco.Kernel/posts/289634051051987

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.  It was the kernel that came with Liquid Smooth ROM.  The kernel developer, chevyno1 (of Simply Stunning MOD), disabled logging in the kernel.  I switched to a different kernel by JDLFG and logging immediately turned on with the next boot.

Comment: Switching kernels helps - in my case Goldenleaf works instead of the old Franco's.

Answer (score 3):

The ROM might call "rm /dev/log/main" during init to cripple logcat. If you can find that line and remove it logcat should be happy.

Comment: Thanks for the hint!  I'll do some grepping and see if that's the issue.

Comment: Why would a rom do that?

Comment: @NoBugs There's a slight speedup if the OS isn't logging as it's running.